# Generic way to test if a type is a (smart) pointer

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

In my code, I need to test if a type given to a template is a pointer -- be it smart or not. According to boost, there is no reliable and generic way to do that (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pointer.html)) -- or is there?

So far, I check for the following:

- A: Can `T` be converted to `void*`?
- B: Does `T` have a `get()` method?
- C: Does `T` have a type called `element_type`?
- D: Does `get()` return an `element_type*`?

If (A || B && C && D), then I conclude that my type must be some kind of pointer.

Here's the template:

```
template <typename T>
class is_pointer_type
{
    typedef struct { char array[1]; } yes;
    typedef struct { char array[2]; } no;

    template <typename C> static yes test_g(decltype(&C::get));
    template <typename C> static no  test_g(...);

    template <typename C> static yes test_e(typename C::element_type*);
    template <typename C> static no  test_e(...);

    enum {
        has_get          = sizeof(test_g<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes),
        has_element_type = sizeof(test_e<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes)
    };

    template <typename Q, bool OK = false>
    struct get { struct type {}; };

    template <typename Q>
    struct get<Q, true>
    {
        typedef decltype(((Q*)nullptr)->get()) type;
    };

    template <typename Q, bool OK = false>
    struct ptr { struct type {}; };

    template <typename Q>
    struct ptr<Q, true>
    {
        typedef typename Q::element_type* type;
    };

public:
    enum {
        types_ok = std::is_same<
                           typename get<T, has_get>::type,
                           typename ptr<T, has_element_type>::type
                   >::value,
        value    = std::is_convertible<T, void*>::value || types_ok
    };
};
```

So far, it seems to work out ok. But is there something wrong with this reasoning? Should I be prepared for unpleasant surprises? What about `const` / `volatile`?

### Update (Motivation):

In the comments you ask for my motivation and they are right, I owe you one. The use case is a Lua - C++ binding library: when exposing a class instance to Lua with `template <typename T> push_value(T value)`, I need to deduce the underlying type `U` in any combination of `T = U const/volatile/*/&` and `T = some_pointer<U>`. I need to know if the underlying class `U` has been registered already with the binder.

Comment: AFAIR pointers-to-member-functions and pointers-to-members can't be converted to `void*`.

Comment: You are doing something boost says cannot be done.  I'd be very ready for surprises...

Comment: Good point! However, in my case that's ok, since I don't deal with those.

Comment: Michael: Hahaha, well put, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: This isn't a generic solution, it is a solution targeted at a particular conceptual notation.  What if you run into a smart pointer that doesn't have an `element_type` but instead has a `ptr_type` or requires the use of a trait?

Comment: The question is: Why? Do you just want to know if you have something that needs dereferencing?

Comment: There are things that can be converted to `void*` but are not smart pointers. Specifically: early attempts at a safe bool idiom, including `std::ios`.

Comment: *Why do you think you need this?* I believe the solution to this "problem" is worthless. However, the solution to the problem you think can be solved like this, but didn't tell us, can be useful.

Comment: Unless you do this for a library, how about declaring template `is_pointer_like<T>` and then just specialize it for plain and smart pointer types you actually use?

Comment: If you devise a "smarter" way to detect smart pointers, someone will unintentionally design a class that happens to match all your criteria while not being a smart pointer.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: that's right. Of course, this implementation can only catch the most common smart pointers, for exotic cases `is_pointer_type` can always be specialized directly.

Comment: @KerrekSB Among other things, yes, I need to know that.

Comment: Rather than testing for `P::element_type` you could test for `std::pointer_traits<P>::element_type` which would be true for some additional types which don't define `element_type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to check if a type is a pointer, either using boost or defining a custom template with a specialization like

```
template <typename C> static no test_pointer(C);
template <typename C> static yes test_pointer(C*);
```

But you can stick with the void* solution if you like it more.

To check smart pointers, I suggest checking for appropriate operators instead. I think a type can be considered to be a smart pointer only if it has both operator* and operator-> defined. So you should check for

```
template <typename C> static yes test_deref(decltype(&C::operator*));
template <typename C> static no test_deref(...);
template <typename C> static yes test_arrow(decltype(&C::operator->));
template <typename C> static no test_arrow(...);
```

and require both results to be 'yes'. So, the final formula can be calculated as "normal pointer || (has operator* && has operator->)".

However, it's a solution only for smart pointers. If you also want to pass types other than smart pointers (other wrappers, collections, etc) to Lua than it's a whole different story and I don't dare to propose a solution for that.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` is a full-fledged smart pointer that doesn't provide `operator->` but `operator[]` instead.

Comment: I get your point, and you're right from your point of view. However, that's exactly why unique_ptr<T[]> should be considered as a smart array instead of a smart pointer despite its name. If you pass such pointers to Lua, you have to add another test directly for such exceptions, and that's a drawback. Are there any similar exceptions we can think of?

Comment: Agreed. Also, `element_type` is not needed with C++11 any more, as it should be the same as `decltype(&C::operator*))`

Comment: In case anybody else is trying to do this with visual studio 2013, it doesn't work correctly sometimes. I tested in 2015 and it does work there, so I think there's just a compiler bug.

I was able to work around this by using `decltype(std::declval<C>().operator*())*` and `decltype(std::declval<C>().operator->())` instead of `decltype(&C::operator*)` and `decltype(&C::operator->)`.