# Observer pattern: how to record a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am using observer pattern in my project. The observer class is designed as:

```
template<typename T>
class BaseModel
{
public:
  T value;
  void GetValue()
  {
    return T;
  }
  void SetValue(T v)
  {
    if ( value != v )
    {
      // notify all observers
    }
  }
};
```

And I can use it as

```
auto val = model->GetValue();
// some calculation
changedVal = val + 1

model->SetValue(val);
```

If `T` is `int, string`, this `BaseModel` works very good.

However, if `T` is a pointer, `model->GetValue()` will return the `pointer`, which share the memory with `model::value`. This means that the calculation on `model->GetValue()` will also change `model::value`. `model->SetValue(changeVal)` will not never notify the observers, because `changeVal` share the same memory with `model::value`.

I have tried some thing:

1. set const for value. But, if `T` is `int **`, the const do not work.
2. I want to force BaseModel do not accept a pointer and `T`. But, I don't know how to decide whether the `T` is a pointer.

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer If C++20 is available to you, you can create a concept from this.

Comment: Or you could specialize `template <typename T> class BaseModel<T*> { … };` if you want it to do something different.

Comment: @sweenish, `std::is_pointer` is a wonderful function. However, I find it failed for smart pointer. For example, `typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr`, `APtr` should be a pointer, but `std::is_pointer<APtr>::value` return false.

Comment: @Ben, I can create a additional `BasePtrModel<T*>`, but I still want to force `BaseModel` do not accepte a pointer as `T`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic way to test if a type is a (smart) pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539305/generic-way-to-test-if-a-type-is-a-smart-pointer)

Comment: @QiangZhang I mean specialization: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Answer (score 1):

`static_assert` with appropriate traits seems enough.

```
template <typename T>
struct is_smart_pointer : std::false_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct is_smart_pointer<std::unique_ptr<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct is_smart_pointer<std::shared_ptr<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename... Ts>
struct is_smart_pointer<std::weak_ptr<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

// ...

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_smart_pointer_v = is_smart_pointer<T>::value;


template<typename T>
class BaseModel
{
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer_v<T>);
    static_assert(!is_smart_pointer_v<T>);
public:
    // ...
};
```

You might then adapt/create more appropriate traits/concept depending of your definition of *"pointer-like"* types (as deferencable (`*p`) and possibly `T::operator->` (so `std::weak_ptr` would not be that kind of types)).